# Angular cordova iOS build getting CordovaError

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

after macos 13.3 update getting this error
xcode 14.3

```
cordova-plugin-firebasex: Preparing Firebase on iOS
Hash value saved at /Users/dhanush/Documents/LIME/AFC/lime-afc-ios/mobile/hash-src/hash-src.json
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'ios-deploy was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.9.2 or greater from https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy into your path, or do 'npm install -g ios-deploy''
at cli.catch.err (/Users/dhanush/Documents/LIME/AFC/lime-afc-ios/mobile/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:29:15)
at process.\_tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

export `SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk`

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling ios-deploy? It sounds like the upgrade may have broken it

Comment: Yes, attempted but after npm install -g iOS-deploy -> archive failed. Here, no need archive. I need build only. If failed, normally getting a build failed message.

Comment: Same error? Different error? If it's a different error, it's probably *another* broken app. Maybe reinstalling the cordova stack will fix the issue in it's entirety?

Comment: /Users/dhanush/Documents/ios/mobile/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.4.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport' from project 'Pods')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65